# Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8545

Tags: testrpc, cpp-ethereum

```
C:\Users\Kane>testrpc


EthereumJS TestRPC v6.0.3 (ganache-core: 2.0.2)

C:\Users\Kane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:74143

...
...

******Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8545******

    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1003:13)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1024:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1366:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1407:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1495:7)
    at Server.server.listen (C:\Users\Kane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:106030:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:50244:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Kane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:21:30)
    at C:\Users\Kane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:64:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kane\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ethereumjs-testrpc\build\cli.node.js:67:10)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: some other apps maybe occupy  8545 port ,   now  I close many apps, it  can  work,  thanks for your question

Answer (score 2):

As @asone mentioned it will be like that for the commands you can do it like this

```
lsof -i:8545
```

and kill the process through the process id(PID)("PID" mentioned on $:lsof -i:8545; on the terminal you get.) by

```
kill -9 <process_id>
```

For reference:https://davidwalsh.name/node-eaddrinuse

Answer (score 0):

This simply means you have another application or service running that is already using the port 8545.

Ensure you have no other instance of testRPC running, and if so, kill it. 
Otherwise you should check for other programs using this port.

You can NetStat your machine to find the Process ID that uses the port, and then find which program is attached to the pId.